# My 2-month-old Persian kitten's fur on tail does not seem right

Tags: cats, health, grooming, skin-condition

My Persian kitten's fur on his tail has not been completely scattered.
The part that has no fur has a dandruff-like disorder and he's scratching it. No fur is growing on that part. He has no ticks nor fleas visible.

He is just 2 months old. When I got him, his tail was already like that.
He is very active and playful and he poops everyday. He has vitamins and is already dewormed.

So I wonder, what is that dandruff-like disorder and how to remove it to grow back his fur?

[image: here whole tail]

[image: dandruff like]

Comment: This might be some infection or tiny parasites you can't see with your eye. Talk to a vet to get this identified and fixed. :)

Answer (score 4):

Any skin related issues should be seen by a veterinarian it could be anything from parasites, allergies (though rare in young animals), had a run in with some chemicals, skin (bacterial to yeast) infection etc.

They may need to do skin scrapings or biopsies to rule out the causes. From pictures alone it is impossible to tell.